# How to float and vertically sort elements?

Tags: html, css

I have elements that are floated and have width = 20% (5 elements per line).

It looks like this:

```
1   2   3   4   5
6   7   8   9   10
11  12  13  14  15
```

What I want now is to "sort" them vertically. That would look like this:

```
1   4   7   10  13
2   5   8   11  14
3   6   9   12  15
```

I can't think of a way to archive that.

Is this possible with CSS only or do I need PHP or JS to archive that?

Comment: and you want to order depending on the content of each element?

Comment: @cralfaro depending the ordner in the html source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS3 [multiple column](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn) layout.

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  -webkit-column-count: 5;
  -moz-column-count: 5;
  column-count: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
</div>
```

Or use CSS3 [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) to do it.

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px; /*20x3*/
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}
.container span {
  flex: 0 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span><span>5</span><span>6</span><span>7</span><span>8</span><span>9</span><span>10</span><span>11</span><span>12</span><span>13</span><span>14</span><span>15</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Very nice. Now I just need to think about a good fallback for IE9

Comment: Multi columns can be hard to control, I also added a flexbox approach. You'll need JS for IE9, but it's totally doable with back-end languages such as PHP I think.